# Cannot uninstall software from Software Center

Tags: software-center

I am using Ubuntu 11.10. When I open the Software Center and click *Installed* on the toolbar all I get is a list down the left hand side with games, graphics, internet etc.

It does not show any software that has been previously installed.

How can I uninstall software from the Software Center?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see installed software in the Ubuntu Software Center go to *Installed*.

[image]

The green check mark shows that an application is installed.

[image]

If you want to remove an application, click on it and then click the *Remove* button.

[image]

Updated

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open Terminal

```
 sudo apt-get update 
 sudo apt-get remove --purge software-center
```

after it done then

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

Comment: i don't think you have understood what i have written.
when i click on the installed option none of the previous software downloads are listed, only the catagories down the left hand side. in other words nothing appears that says install or remove. Hope this makes my question alot clearer
regards derek

Comment: open terminal and type this without quotes  "sudo apt-get remove --purge software-center " then "apt-get install software-center" try it & update

Comment: try to update ur question

Answer (score 2):

try to uninstall it from terminal

sudo apt-get autoremove (app name)

and about this problem try to search in software sources may be you put repository broken or something like that and remove it from other software tab in software sources

and try this command may help you

1. sudo apt-get check
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get upgrade
4. sudo apt-get autoclean
5. sudo apt-get purge

and restart afte that try again

if not you can do that but i'm sure the won't help you but try it remove ubuntu software center by this command in terminal

sudo apt-get autoremove software-center

and return install it

sudo apt-get install software-center