# Software center not showing installed programs

Tags: unity, software-center

First time running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I open Software Centre and click on <kbd>Installed</kbd>, it just shows a blank page, nothing comes up, but I have installed programs. Any ideas?

Comment: Preinstalled programs or you installed the programs yourself? If it was preinstalled, then it's not gonna show there.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```

Comment: Thanks PaperBuntu.  All these commands are new to me. Help appreciated.

Comment: Sorry to sound stupid, but every time I enter the terminal, I click CTRL>ALT+F1  and it takes me to a completely new window. Is it possible for me to open a terminal window and edit WITHIN my desktop, so I can copy your code into the terminal without constantly swapping backwards and forwards between terminal and desktop?

Comment: I tried your code and it seemed to work, but still no apps showing in "Installed" in Software Center. Also, the "Software Updater" has disappeared from the left pane of programs.  I'm a bit lost here. When I do a search for this program in Software Center,  it finds it, but it offers me no way of opening it, or recovering it, just "shows me" that it exists somehow...and when I look for "software updater" in ClassicMenuIndicator, it doesn't show up there. How can I find 'Software updater' and start using it again?

Comment: ok, I figured out how to use the Terminal on my desktop, but still can't find "Software Updater".

Comment: sudo apt-get install update-manager

Comment: to copy the above command select the whole line and ctrl + c, and then go to terminal and press ctrl + shift + v,

Comment: to switch between apps , press Windows Button (superKey) + w, you would be amazed :)

Comment: to install software center type this `sudo apt-get install software-center`

Comment: I recommend you to read unix concepts and applications by Sumitabha das , it's a nice book :), you would become an ubuntu expert in no Time

Comment: I'm not allowed to say 'thank you', apparently, so I won't offend Linux etiquette by doing so. :-)   BUT - re-installing Software Center did NOT solve the problem.  Installed programs still not showing.  Only by clicking categories on left.

Comment: sometimes , it's better to use an alternative , just write this in the terminal  if you want to install something i  `sudo apt-get install app_name` for example , `sudo apt-get install  wine` ( wine is a software that helps you run windows program in ubuntu) and likewise you can google for some software for example :  best software for video players in ubuntu , and get that software name and then `sudo apt-get install software_name`

Answer (score 0):

I found some possible solutions here I believe:
[Ubuntu Software Center Issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337150/problem-with-ubuntu-software-center-cant-install-anything)

Basically it gives some commands to fix any possible broken packages and install necessary library files:
    $ sudo apt-get autoclean 
    $ sudo apt-get autoremove
    $ sudo apt-get --purge remove
    $ sudo apt-get -f install

[Software Center Troubleshoot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105610/cannot-uninstall-software-from-software-center) 
If that doesn't work you can uninstall and purge the software center and re-install it.
sudo apt-get update 
 sudo apt-get remove --purge software-center
sudo apt-get install software-center

Hope this helps, 
Subutai

Comment: Sorry but this didn't work. Still no apps showing in 'installed' in Soft Center.  Also Software updater has disappeared. @subotai